# mySQL InnoDB tablespace move to network drive

Tags: mysql, tablespaces, network, files

In Windows 10 with mySQL 8.0.26, I am seeking to move a set of rarely used but occasionally necessary tables from my working SSD to another physical device with more space.

I have attempted to move the schema holding these tables using [this procedure](https://www.moxio.com/blog/28/moving-individual-mysql-tables-on-disk), but in Windows instead of Ubuntu.

The devices available are either shared SMB drives over WAN connections or a local PC on the same LAN.

The latter (local PC) is my preferred choice, as WAN-connections would much slower.

I can use the DATA DIRECTORY directive and that procedure to successfully move a schema to a different known directory on my default (C:) drive.  I have the local LAN drive shared as D:, but I get errors when I attempt to access it for table creation:

```
10 [ERROR] [MY-012611] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
10 [ERROR] [MY-012612] [InnoDB] The error means the system cannot find the path specified. It might be too long or it might not exist.
8 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File \\192.168.30.151: 'CreateDirectory' returned OS error 261.
```

I understand the caveat that tablespaces on network drives, even local, will be significantly slower to process operations.  But I would like to open up more space on the local SSD without having to restore dumps to use these tables on occasion.

I've tried using the drive letter, UNC file string, but none have worked.

Most of the documentation for moving tablespaces is (understandably) in the Linux OS.  I'm using mySQL not as a server but as a data analysis tool, and I have to be in Windows.

Comment: Keep fishing for fixes to UNC; `File \\192.168.30.151` sounds "wrong".  Furthermore, inside my.cnf,  Also, `/` works even when Windows needs backslash.

Comment: Performance is not the only problem with network drives. They also tend to be unavailable sometimes, if the network has a glitch or the SMB connection is broken. This will cause bad errors in MySQL Server when InnoDB can't find the tablespace. This happens on Linux too, if one tries to put tablespaces on an NFS or SMB shared volume. It's not good. You should just get a larger drive, or a second server with its own MySQL Server.